# Xamarin forms Deleting an image returns true, but I can still see the image in the file system?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, xamarin.forms, filesystems, delete-file

I am using Dependency service to delete a file that I just took using the media.plugin for Xamarin forms:

```
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
    {
        Directory = "CameraTakenPhotos",
        SaveToAlbum = false,
        CompressionQuality = 75,
        CustomPhotoSize = 50,
        PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight,
        MaxWidthHeight = 2000,
        DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Rear
    });

if (file == null)
    return;
var ImagePath = file.Path;
await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

try
{
    var imageExists = Helpers.StorageHelper.FileExists(ImagePath);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error occured while checking if image is available: " + ex);
}

image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
{
    var stream = file.GetStream();
    file.Dispose();
    return stream;
});

//deleting the image
try
{
    var deletationResutl = Helpers.StorageHelper.DeleteFileByPath(ImagePath);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error while deleting the image " + ex);
}
```

The DeleteFileByPath function returns true=> file is deleted. 
but I can still see the image on my phone using ES File Explorer

the implementation for the method is:

```
public bool DeleteFileByPath(string filePath)
{
    File.Delete(filePath);

    if (File.Exists(filePath))
        return false;//not deleted
    else
        return true;//deleted
}
```

Could someone help me with this issue, please?

**UPDATE#1:**
I created another method to check if the image is there or not. It's telling me that the image is there!

So, the deletion has failed, but it told me that it was deleted the first time. This is the method I developed for testing:

```
var imageExists = Helpers.StorageHelper.FileExists(ImagePath);

if(imageExists)
    await DisplayAlert("Confirmation", "Image is there", "Ok");
else
    await DisplayAlert("Confirmation", "No image was found", "Ok");
```

**UPDATE#2:**
When I try to delete an image that doesn't exists, I am getting a false which is the expected behavior.

I am confused and lost. I will try with iOS and see if it's a bug or something

**UPDATE#3:**
The same behavior is occurring for iOS.

Comment: 'I am using Dependency service to delete a file' Out of interest why are you doing this? You can just call File.Delete in the shared code. One thing I would suggest trying is to comment out the setting of the image.Source and run again to see if the file is still remaining on the device. That is called asynchronously so something could be holding on to the file and even possibly writing it out again if it isn't there...

Comment: I am using Dependency service because deleting the file might be different on each platform. It will also give me more control.

I hard coded the file path and still can't delete it even after I close the app.

Comment: In my experience (which is admittedly not vast with Xamarin) the action of deleting is the same on all platforms, it is actually the folder structure that is different on the different platforms but that in this scenario is the job of the MediaPlugin to supply it to you. Anyhow that is probably not what is causing the issue. As I mentioned above **try commenting out the setting of the image.Source and run again to see if the file is still remaining on the device**

Comment: I tried and still getting the same issue.

Comment: who would have thought that deleting files would be so hard. I tried before the PCLStorage plugin and faced similar issue. I also tried this code with iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very eqmberssing but apparently it was a typo in the helper class. I was calling the method "FileExists" instead of "DeleteFile"

This is the correct helper method:

```
public static bool DeleteFileByPath(string filePath)
    {
        return Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>().DeleteFileByPath(filePath);
    }
```

Comment: is it still required to use a platform specific Delete method? Can I just call File.Delete from the .NET Standard code?

Comment: from my research, you can't call "File" from the PCL because it's specific to each platform. I am not sure about new releases of Xamarin since they are moving to NetStandard.You can try to call the System.IO.DeleteFile(string path) from the your .NET standard project and see if you can import that library.

Comment: I would like to find a better solution myself since this gave me ideas to utilize the local storage and access the file system which is a step ahead in development instead of being stuck with local DBs or plugins that might stop the support like PCLStorage which was last updated almost 3 years ago.

Comment: Just a heads up in my .NET Standard Project I was able to delete the file and confirm.                     System.IO.File.Delete(file.Path);

Comment: @aherrick Thanks for the update. .NET Standard sounds awesome , I need to try it out and see if the API is enough to cover all platform specific interactions that I need in my projects.

Comment: It’s worth it. I’ve updated all my PCL forms apps to standard at this point